# Loop through combination method in ruby

Tags: ruby, combinations

I am going through a question over at coderbytes, but got stuck. I am supposed to write a method that takes in an array and checks to see if the sum of any combination of numbers in the array equal the max number in the array. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers. Here's what I have written.

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  if arr.combination(2).any? {|x,y| x + y == arr.max}
    return "true"
  else 
    return "false"
  end
end
```

The only issue is that I want to iterate through the combination input with each number in `(2..arr.length)`. Any one have an easy way to do this.

Also, `arr.combination(2).any? {|x,y| x + y == arr.max}`on its own returns true when the aforementioned condition is met which leads me to think that maybe I don't need `if`. Anyone know any way to have the method return true without an `if` statement?

Comment: Try something like this: `(2..arr.size).any? { |n| arr.combination(n).any? { |c| c.reduce(:+) == arr.max } }`. That is, condition on the number of elements of arr for which you are generating combinations. This may not be the most efficient approach, however.  One should also check to see if `arr` is empty or contains a single element, and if negative values are permitted, whether the max value is to be included in combinations that are summed requires clarification.

Comment: Why does it matter if there are negative numbers?

Comment: Suppose the array contained `-5,2,3,10` and `10` was the largest element in the array.  Those four numbers total `10`. Is it a valid combination, considering that it contains the largest number? If not, would it make a difference if the array contained two `10`s? That would have to be clarified.

Comment: You don't need an `if` because Ruby has an implicit return: the value of the last expression in a function is the return value of that function.